# Connection Refused Error Java/Linux

Tags: java, linux, sockets, port

I'm trying to move an existing project over to a new (linux) server environment (note, I have no direct access to the code nor do I have any knowledge about the project in general - talk about a great start), upon starting the project I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: <servername>:1459 [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server <servername>:1459 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server <servername>:1459 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException:     Connection refused]]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1562)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:634)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.jboss.Shutdown.main(Shutdown.java:214)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server <servername> [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server <servername>:1459 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:274)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1533)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server <servername>:1459 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:248)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:276)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:84)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:77)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:244)
    ... 5 more
```

Now, I've opened the port in question to see whether there are any changes when I do so, alas, nothing happens.

I'm sorry about this very vague level of information, but it's really all I have, I'll gladly provide what I can if you have any ideas what could be at fault here.

Regards,

Dennis

Comment: I don't think this has to do anything with Java. Much more firewall rules, and OS settings... Until you can do a 'telnet <server> <port>', and _not_ get a connection refused, this is a configuration issue.

Comment: I'm not saying I assume it's Java - I'm open to suggestions regarding all error sources obviously. I just haven't worked with Linux Servers before, neither am I particularly fit when it comes to that I'm afraid.

Comment: So this has worked prviously running on a Windows server. I'd say get help from the owner of the Linux box, and figure out the issue together as otherwise this will take much longer than it should. Provide which ports you need open, and it should be a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

`Connection refused` is the error you get when you try to `connect` a TCP/IP socket to a service that isn't there.

Usually, this means that the computer making the connection was actually able to reach the remote server, but that no service was listening on the specified port.

This is unlikely to be a network configuration problem.  If the port was being blocked you'd usually either just see a timeout, or on some firewalls, a `connection reset by peer` error.